# How to convert external data with Decimal into Value in Avro

Tags: rust, avro

I'm working on iceberg-rs and iceberg support avro format metadata. When writting metadata, I use [append_ser](https://docs.rs/apache-avro/latest/apache_avro/struct.Writer.html#method.append_ser) provided by writer in avro. It works fine because I only need to implement Serialize trait in iceberg data(external data) so that it can be passed in append_ser directly to write.

But I find that I can't include Decimal type beacause the [serializer](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/rust/avro/src/ser.rs) seems can't support decimal.

I know that there is not decimal type in serde data model so it may hard to support to serde it in Serializer. Do rust-avro have provided a way to solve problem? Maybe serialize it in Fixed and process it in encode phase? (https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/60796e5df4581589717cfa32952da792dec79b68/lang/rust/avro/src/encode.rs#L117)